# Sum of an array

Tags: ruby

So in Python `sum([])` will yield 0, which is pretty important.

Whereas in ruby `[].reduce(:+)` will give nil, of course the ternary operator isn't a replacement, because:

```
(my_complicated_mapping).empty? ? 0 : (my_complicated_mapping).reduce(:+)
```

Will call `my_complicated_mapping` twice. Therefore the obvious method is:

```
res = my_complicated_mapping
res = (res.empty? ? 0 : res.reduce(:+))
```

I think there must be a neater way to do this though.

Comment: `nil.to_i #=> 0`, so you could tack `to_i` onto `reduce`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Just do as @mikej suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reduce you can specify the initial value as the first parameter e.g.

```
my_complicated_mapping.reduce(0, :+)
```

then if the list is empty you'll get 0 instead of `nil`. You can check the different alternative ways of using `reduce` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

or if using a block for `reduce` it would be:

```
my_complicated_mapping.reduce(0) { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

i.e. a single parameter with with initial value and supplying your block.

It's important to understand *why* `reduce` returns `nil` in the case of the empty array: If you don't specify an explicit initial value for memo, then the first element of the array is used as the initial value of memo, which of course doesn't exist in the empty case.

Comment: What does that look like in block form? It seems kind of magical.

Comment: @user3467349 updated with another example and some more details - hope that helps make it clearer!

Comment: Ah thanks, the later example is even more useful - the reason I wasn't able to use `reduce` instead of `map` at first was because the `{ |sum, i| }` block was assigning the first value of the range to `sum` - which was not a practical behaviour, specifying a value to `reduce` appears to fix that. Although that's even more magical! Not sure why it was designed like that (e.g. `(1..4).reduce(0) {}` will yield 4 iterations, where as `(1..4).reduce  {}` yields only 3 iterations with `1` assigned to sum.

Comment: I think the reason for this design is because using the first first element as the initial memo is what you want in a lot of circumstances e.g. something like finding the longest word `words.reduce { |memo, word| word.length > memo.length ? word : memo }`

Comment: Ah, that kind of makes sense. Still a little weird having a different number of iterations based on the presence on an argument to `reduce` though.

Comment: In most languages, these are two different operations, e.g. in Haskell, they are `foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a` and `foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`, in Scala, they are `GenTraversableOnce[+A].foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B` and `TraversableOnce[+A].reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B`. In Ruby, they are overloaded into one method. But still, they are two distinct operations: in the general case, the accumulator can be of a different type than the elements and the folding operator has type `(ACC, EL) -> ACC`. In the restricted case, the accumulator has the same type as

Comment: the elements and the folding operator has type `(EL, EL) -> EL`, plus, reducing an empty list is an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_i` to convert `nil` to `0`

```
[].reduce(:+).to_i
# => 0
```

Incase Array contains float values, using `to_f` can help:

```
[].reduce(:+).to_f
# => 0.0
```

Comment: What if it's an array of `Float`?

Comment: using `.to_f` would make more sense then.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give 0 as initial parameter? Like

```
my_complicated_mapping.reduce(0, :+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `inject`:

```
my_complicated_mapping.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e }
```

Comment: `inject` is just a synonym for `reduce`.